# Forward mail from US to Brazil

Tags: usa, relocation, brazil

I am moving permanently from the US to Brazil.

How can I make all my letters be forwarded from my old US address to my new Brazilian address?

Comment: I tried to get forward for Mexico and they told me at the post office they don't forward mail out of the Country only in the Usa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

International Mail Forwarding is what you'll be after. Most major national postal services offer it, for a fee

USPS [offers mail forwarding](https://www.usps.com/manage/forward.htm). The price depends on how long you want it for, how quickly or often to forward mail etc. Full details [on their website](https://www.usps.com/manage/forward.htm)

Not so well explained on that bit of the site is the international part. If you go to the [USPS FAQ entry on Change of Address - General Information](http://faq.usps.com/?articleId=221220), then scroll down quite a bit, you'll find this helpful piece:

> **How do I file a Change of Address for an international address?**
>
> You cannot submit a Change of Address online for an international 
>   address.
>
> If you are moving to an International address outside of the United States, you will need to fill out the same Change of Address (COA) form (PS Form 3575) that is filed for a domestic move at your local Post Office™.

So, you'll need to fill out the form mentioned, head to your local post office, and arrange + pay for the international mail forwarding in person.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at this Change of Address page, but couldn't find international info. Do you know of the fees for that? It seems that intra-US is a one-time fee of $1.05.

Comment: I don't, sorry. Assuming your local post office isn't too far, probably easiest to just pop in next time you're passing + ask + edit my answer to list it!

Comment: Did it today. It's weird because they ask you to write the international address in the same form as you would write a US address, so you gotta stuck the country name in there somewhere and adapt the fields to the specific country. And there is NO FEE.